# Existence of fixed point proof in interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, proof-verification

I had to proof:

If $f$ is differentiable between $(-\infty, \infty)$ and $f'(x)<1$. Then it has at most one fixed point.

My proof was:

Suppose there are 2 fixed points. Then $f(x_{1})=x_{1}$ and $f(x_{2})=x_{2}$. By the mean value theorem $f'(c) = \frac{f(x_{2})-f(x_{1})}{x_{2}-x_{1}} = \frac{x_{2}-x_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}} = 1$ and this contradicts $f'(x)<1$, therefore, it has at the most one fixed point.

I don't know if my proof was rigurous enough or even correct. I would appreciate if someone could let me know my mistakes, thanks.

Comment: You want $[x_1,x_2]$ to be an interval i.e $x_2>x_1$ you can assume it WLOG ( minor detail, if $x_1>x_2$ just take $[x_2,x_1]$ doesn't change the result). You could also point out why is the function difderentiable on $[x_1,x_2]$(also pretty minor detail)$ otherwise it's good.